# Performance issues while exporting kendo grid data to pdf

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, export-to-pdf

I have a grid with a big set of records(round 10,000 on an average). I have implemented server side paging on the grid to retrieve 50 records at a time. Everything with the grid is working perfectly fine till I decide to do a export to pdf from the grid.

When I try to do the same the export takes round 5-6 mins on an average to complete. I tried to debug on the server side and realised that multiple calls to the server were being made to retrieve the data for the export which probably was eating up the time. I alternatively tried to modify the set of records retrieved to 1000 at a time so as to reduce the server calls to eventually reduce the time taken for the export. But now while trying to export to pdf the page crashes. I changed the set of records to 500 but the crash still happens when exporting.

On another note the export to excel works pretty fast in round ~4 secs. When trying to debug I found out that there was only a single call to the server made while exporting to excel and this renders the entire set of data as well.

Please note that I am using the kendo defaults for exporting to pdf and excel with the grid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need implement server side export.
kendo says :

> Important
>
> When the allPages option is set to true and serverPaging is enabled, the Grid will make a "read" request for all data. If the data items are too many, the browser may become unresponsive. Consider implementing server-side export for such cases.

[look this page](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/pdf-export#export-of-all-pages)

Full example : [link](https://github.com/telerik/ui-for-aspnet-mvc-examples/tree/master/grid/pdf-export-server-side)